# What is the reason behind args() returning only one value when return() method is used?

Tags: python, args

## The code that I am using is below:

def myfunc(*args):
       for i in (args):
           if i % 2 == 0:
               return i

```
myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Current Output is:

Output : 2

Expectation:
I would like to return all the even values instead of just one value alone.

Comment: a function stops execution the moment it sees a return. That's how return works. You have to "collect" all even values first, and then return the result.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the 1st value that satisfies the `if condition`. You need to store all the values in `list` then return after `for loop` is completed.

```
def func(*args):
    temp = []
    for i in (args):
        if i%2==0:
            temp.append(i)
    return temp

print(func(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Output:

```
[2,4,6]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, you cannot return more than one value. So you can add all you even value to a list and use that.

```
def myfunc(*args):
   list1 = list()
   for i in (args):
       if i % 2 == 0:
           list1.append(i)
   return list1

myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Alternately, you can use a generator function to get values one by one.

```
def myfunc(*args):
   for i in (args):
       if i % 2 == 0:
           yield i


something = myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: The `yield` solution will produce only an object of generator in `Python-2`. Need to add `list(myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6))` to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why for args() returning only one value when using return()?

-- args doesn't return anything. You are just passing your input to the function through that.
-- You are also using a return in your for loop which causes the function to return abandoning the loop.

Try the below code:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [x for x in args if x%2 == 0]

print myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function stops while the first `return` expression is executed. An alternative is:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    result = []
    for i in (args):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result
myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```